# Firmware Bug when booting Ubuntu involving ACPI region and SGX

Tags: dual-boot, acpi, firmware, sgx

When I boot to ubuntu, I get the following errors shown in the picture below. I have deleted ubuntu, but even when I wanted to install it again from flash drive, I got the same errors. I have the latest version of my BIOS. I could not downgrade BIOS as it gave me an error that my version was too old. Also, after giving me these errors, ubuntu still boots normally.
I am on dual boot with windows 10.
PC name : ASUS ROG GL552VW

Is it worth a try wiping my hard-drive. Could this solve the problem?

The errors:

[image: The errors]

PS. There are also other questions in this thread with the same problem. I saw all of them but their solutions did not work for me.

Comment: @karel Same problem, but can't apply the solutions since I there is no option for ACPI or TPM in my BIOS

Comment: Now there are no more duplicate close votes for that reason after I retracted my own duplicate question close vote.